# Min-width on a Centered <div> CSS and HTML

Tags: css

I am attempting to write a simple 404 (Page not Found) error page for my website: bazingamanphdgaming.t15.org. This is my code so far:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>404 - Not found</title>
    <style>
        #title {
            position:fixed;
            top:40%;
            color:white;
            font-size:40px;
            text-align:center;
            width:100%
        }
        #link {
            position:fixed;
            top:45%;
            font-size:20px;
            text-align:center;
            width:100%
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:black">
    <div id="title"><b>404 - Page not found</b></div>
    <div id="link"><br />
        <a style="color:white" href="http://bazingamanphdgaming.t15.org">
            Return to the BazingaManPHD Gaming home page.
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

However when I reduce the browser window's width the bold text in the #title  goes over the link going back to the homepage. This is a screenshot:

[image: Figure 1]

Of course to fix this problem I would need to put a min-width property on the #title  like so:

```
<div id="title" style="min-width:200px"><b>404 - Page not found</b></div>
```

I am using 200px as an example there, but it doesn't seen to work, whatever size I put it as. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could enable vertical align by setting `display:table` and `display:table-cell` to the containers.

```css
html,body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
body{display:table}
.page {
    background:black;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.title {
    color:white;
    font-size:40px;
}
.link {
    font-size:20px;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
    <div class="title">404 - Page not found</div>
    <a class="link" href="http://bazingamanphdgaming.t15.org">Return to the BazingaManPHD Gaming home page.</a>
</div>
```

This way it will center whatever you put into it.

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/f6c1wupL/1/

Answer (score 3):

Simply add this to your CSS:

```
#title {
    white-space: nowrap;
    /* rest of your styles */
}
```

This will prevent the text in `#title` from wrapping.

Comment: Thankyou that was part of the solution but is there any way I could do that but have a horizontal scroll bar on the bottom so if a user is on a phone or a similar sized screen they could scroll along and see it all?

Comment: @odixon Yes there is, and it requires more modifications. See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/t4p2xw0L/

Answer (score 0):

here is a fiddle to take a look.
Basically there were a couple problems in your css.
Setting the position of elements to fixed takes them out of the natural flow.
If your thinking about the page as a piece of paper these fixed elements are floating above the paper wherever you place them.
By putting them relative you are putting them onto the piece of paper so the position of other elements can have an effect on their position. i.e bumping them out of the way.

by marking them relative the 'top' selector no longer works instead to move the items down the page give them a margin-top to offset them from the the bounds of the body(it's parent element).

```
#title {
position:relative;
margin-top:40%;
color:white;
font-size:40px;
text-align:center;
width:100%;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/crnc6ht5/